# Converting Universal app to iPhone only app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-universal-app

I started developing an application in a universal configuration, but later the requirement changed and the application turned out to be iPhone only. Now how do I change the application configuration to fulfill this criterion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if u're using xcode 4.2

- navigate to project navigator
- select your project
- selct target > your project's name > summary
- change the devices from "universal" to "iphone"

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Xcode 5.0

- Select Project Navigator
- Select your project file
- Make sure your project file is selected and not a target
- Select the Build Settings tab
- Scroll Down to deployment section and search through that for "Targeted Device Family" or search that key term in the search field at the top
- Change iphone/ipad to iphone only

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Xcode 6.0

- Select Project Navigator
- Select Your Project File
- Select the General Tab
- Scroll down to deployment info
- Select Device drop down and change to Universal to iPhone only

Answer (score 1):

see this link,it will help you to solve your problem

[“Downgrading” a Universal iPad/iPhone app to iPhone only](http://blog.johnmckerrell.com/2010/06/03/downgrading-a-universal-ipadiphone-app-to-iphone-only/)

Comment: you can see this link also:http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/7/converting-to-a-universal-app-part-i.html